# Posterior Predictive Density of Linear Regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, normal-distribution, predictive-models, density-function

I'm trying to derive the Posterior Predictive Density of a Linear Regression Model with a diffuse, uninformative prior such that we have:

$y_{i} = x_{i}'\beta + \varepsilon_{i}$  with $\varepsilon_{i} \sim N(0,\sigma^{2})$  Equation (1)

We have the density of $y_{N+1}$ given $x_{N+1}, \beta,\sigma^{2}$ as

$p(y_{N+1}|x_{N+1},\beta,\sigma^{2}) = (\frac{1}{\sigma (2\pi)^{1/2}})\exp(\frac{-(y_{N+1}-x'_{N+1}\beta)^2}{2\sigma^{2}})$  Equation (2)

Following some notes on Bayesian Econometrics the definition of posterior predictive density is:

$p(y_{N+1}|x_{N+1},y) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}p(y_{N+1}|x_{N+1},\beta,\sigma^{2})p(\beta,\sigma^{2}|y)d\sigma^{2}d\beta$.   Equation (3)

Then under a prior specification $p(\beta,\sigma^{2}) \propto \sigma^{-2}$,
the posterior predictive density is given by:

$p(y_{N+1}|x_{N+1},y) \propto \Big((N-k) + \frac{(y_{N+1}-x'_{N+1}\hat{\beta})'M(y_{N+1}-x'_{N+1}\hat{\beta})}{(y-X\hat{\beta})'(y-X\hat{\beta})/(N-k)}\Big)^{-\frac{(N-k+1)}{2}}$         Equation (4)

with $M = (1 + x'_{N+1}(X'X)^{-1}x_{N+1})^{-1}$

I would really appreciate some intuition of how I can arrive to Equation 4. I am able to derive marginal, conditional and predictive distributions in almost any kind of shape but I really got stuck in this normal gaussian approach.

Comment: If $p(\beta, \sigma^2) \propto \sigma^{-2}$ then how can it be normalized? The integral over $x^{-1}$ diverges. It would make more sense if $p(\beta, \sigma) \propto \sigma^{-2}$ for $\sigma \ge 0.$

Comment: @Bridgeburners this derivation is from a book.